# Python2 Tkinter Grid of buttons, each with a command to change it's display text

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, iteration

I made a basic roguelike in python2 which uses levels based on 2d arrays, like so:

```
map = [
['a','b'],
['c','d']
]
```

As you can imagine, this is tedious when it comes to big levels (20x20 or 30x30), so I decided to create a level editor in Tkinter. My idea was to have a large grid of buttons and a text box. You enter a number into the text box, and when you click on a button, that button's label changes to the number (Each number corresponds to a sprite in the level). Very simple.

My issue is when I create this grid of buttons:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        Button(
            root,
            text=str(i)+','+str(j),
            command = ???
            ).grid(row=i,column=j)
```

This certainly creates a grid of buttons. However, I have no idea what to put as the command argument. I've tried a few things, but they all come back to the same issue: *Since I'm creating each button through a for-loop, they can't be contained in a variable.* For example, I can't say:

```
...
for j in range(10):
    myButton = Button(...)
...
```

Because this would overwrite it with each iteration.

I've spent a few hours trying to find a solution to this, and I can't find one. Is there something I'm missing? Sorry if I haven't explained my problem very well.
[Here's my full code if you need it.](http://pastebin.com/JFZRdL3F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning to a *variable* like `myButton`, assign to a dict, list, or other sequence *of* `Button` class.  Using a list:

```
buttons = []
...
for j in range(10):
    buttons.append(Button(...))
```

Or using dict:

```
buttons = {}
for j in range(10):
    buttons[j] = Button(...)
```

Comment: Oh man that's genius! Well, it's probably common knowledge, but I certainly didn't think of it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, a good solution would be to subclass `Button` with a class that has its command pre-set, and then make a 2-dimensional array of your `Button` subclass. That way, it would almost exactly mirror the structure that you are creating. So something like this:

```
class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, command=lambda: command(), **kwargs)
        # Whatever else you want to set, do it here
    def command(self):
        # You want the button to scroll through letters when you click, 
        # if I understand the question right. You'll have to implement 
        # get_next_letter() yourself. 
        self.text = self.get_next_letter()
# later...

buttons = [[MyButton() for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
for i in buttons:
    for j in i: 
        # Set up your grid, etc. here.
```